# In Windows 8.1, how can I configure File History to backup *some* of my SkyDrive folders?

Tags: onedrive, windows-8.1-preview, file-history

I want File History to back up all of the folders in my SkyDrive except for the media folders (Music, Pictures, Videos, Podcasts). My media folders are "available online only", the rest of "available offline". Right now File History does not back up any of the content in my SkyDrive, and I can't seem to find a way to configure which folders it backs up.

I found some sources that say if my SkyDrive is available offline, it will be added to File History. But I don't want to make my entire SkyDrive available offline, just the non-media folders.

Answer (score 3):

With Windows 8.1 Preview, Microsoft silently removed the ability to backup SkyDrive folders using File History. Making folders available offline does not help. In Windows 8, File History backup was supported. File History backup of SkyDrive Pro is still supported in Windows 8.1.

I case you want to switch to Windows 7 Files Backup: this was removed too with Windows 8.1.
Windows 7 Image backup is still there, but difficult to find: A link in the bottom left corner of Control Panel -> All Control Panel Items -> File History.

Answer (score 1):

With Win 8.1 **Update 1** MS silently reenabled File History backup of OneDrive folders.